# AWS Code build Error: "CLIENT_ERROR: Submodule error authentication required for primary source and source version refs/heads/master"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I have a git repo in codecommit that has submodules. These are also in codecommit.

When I run the build has this error: `CLIENT_ERROR: Submodule error authentication required for primary source and source version refs/heads/master` at phase `DOWNLOAD_SOURCE`

I can't find anything on the internet about this error.

The codebuild role has full access to codecommit permissions.

[image]

Comment: I had to create a pipeline to create the source.  A bit weird that source means basically copy paste the whole repo from codecommit to s3 bucket. Then building needs to read from a zip from s3 bucket. Very slow...

Comment: Thanks for the insight